# prove that graph with girth=5 has at least $k^2+1$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

given a graph G with a girth of 5, prove that for $delta(G)>=k$ (minimum degree), G has a least $k^2+1$ vertices.

Can anyone provide a hint or an approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick

- a vertex,
- its neighbours,
- and their neighbours apart from the original vertex

Comment: thanks, that helped